# ARIMA Question: Is it more preferable to use monthly data over quarterly, or vice-versa?

Tags: arima

I'm an actuary trying to model future losses. I have the ability to use monthly or quarterly data, and I'm curious if there is any material difference in using either periods. I understand there may be no simple answer, so I'll provide more info if needed to get a substantive response.

Thank you!
StrappingYL

Answer (score 1):

It's hard (I would say "impossible") to answer this in an abstract sense. Which approach is better could vary in different examples.

Try both approaches, forecasting on both levels, and then either aggregate the monthly forecasts to quarterly, or disaggregate the quarterly ones to months, dependending on what granularity you are interested in.

Alternatively, forecast on both granularities and then combine the forecasts using [the optimal combination approach of Hyndman et al. (2011, *Computational Statistics & Data Analysis*)](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.csda.2011.03.006). When the hierarchy in question is one of time, this has been called MAPA by [Kourentzes et al. (2014, *International Journal of Forecasting*)](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ijforecast.2013.09.006).

Comment: I'll run both models and compare the results. Thank you for the insight!